# Access Report First Page vertical, second Horizontal

Tags: ms-access, report

I am quit newbie with the microsft acess 2003 Reports.

I would like to have a first page of the report designed in vertical, and the second one with some subinforms designed in horizontal.

Is that possible?

I'm trying the following code:

```
Private Sub Report_Page()
 If (Page Mod 2 = 0) Then
  Me.Printer.Orientation = acPRORLandscape
  Else
  Me.Printer.Orientation = acPRORPortrait
 End If
End Sub
```

But it doesnt work properly..
Regards,

Comment: Why would you want to do that in the same report? I am guessing you could simply use 2 different reports for what you need.

Comment: I need to design a file for a lampost vertically on the A side of a paper sheet and on its B side design the properties os its lamp, lines, auxiliar equipment,etc but horizontally...i need to print 6000 lamposts (sheets) with this design

Comment: It would make far more sense to simply rotate the design on the second page, not the print orientation.

Answer (score 1):

In Access there is no way to do this.  You must create 2 separate reports in order to do it.

In some instances you can change the layout of a report in code using:

```
Reports("<Report Name>").Printer.Orientation = acPRORLandscape
```

But the results aren't always consistent.  And I've never heard of anyone successfully changing orientation within a report.